# Principal divisor associated to an element algebraic over the ground field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral scheme over a field $k$, and let $r\in K(X)^*$. This gives me the principal divisor $\mathrm{div}(r)$. What can I say about this divisor if $r$ is algebraic over $k$?

I suspect that in this case, $\mathrm{div}(r)$ is trivial, but I don't find a way to show this.

I ask this because in many proofs, one uses that either $\mathrm{div}(r)$ is trivial, or $r$ defines a non-constant function to $\mathbb A^1_k$ (or both), but I don't know how to show this in the case that $k$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: Write $r^n=-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ir^i$ and apply $v_p$ on both sides. What do you get if suppose $v_p(r)\ne 0$?

Comment: Oh, I see, this gives me $n\cdot\nu_p(r)=-\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}\cdot\nu_p(r)$, hence $\nu_p(r)=0$.

Comment: Not quite. The $v_p$ of the sum is the minimum of $iv_p(r)$.

Comment: Oh, of course. But still, this gives me $n\cdot\nu_p(r)=(n-1)\cdot\nu_p(r)$ or $n\cdot\nu_p(r)=0$, depending on the sign, both leading to $\nu_p(r)=0$.

Comment: @user26857 I know your comments are a few months old, but I hope you'll still answer my question, as it is somewhat related to another problem I am working on: Why is $\nu_p$ of the sum the minimum of $i\nu_p(r)$ (for $i=0,\ldots,n-1$ is suppose).

Comment: @user114158 If $v(a)>v(b)$ then $v(a+b)=v(b)$.